# An exercise from a linear algebra book (hoffman and kunze)

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

I am not sure how to solve this exercise:

> Find all solutions of $$\begin{align*}2x_1-3x_2-7x_3+5x_4+2x_5&=-2\\
> x_1-2x_2-4x_3+3x_4+x_5&=-2\\
> 2x_1\qquad-4x_3+2x_4+x_5&=3\\
> x_1-5x_2-7x_3+6x_4+2x_5&=-7\;.
> \end{align*}$$

my row-reduced echelon matrix is:

$$\pmatrix{1&0&-2&1&0&1\\
0&1&1&-1&0&2\\
0&0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0}$$

I don't see my mistake right now, I think I did something wrong xD 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you think you did something wrong?

Comment: Please double-check to make sure that I copied the equations correctly.

Comment: You might want to bring this matrix into a canonical form, you are not done yet (and double check your work if you think you made a mistake along the way)

Comment: @Belgi, the matrix is certainly in reduced row-echelon form, which is canonical. What did you have in mind?

Comment: @GerryMyerson - my mistake.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I made a mistake, thanks for catching it. (I used Octave, but must have made a mistake, the svd gives 3 non-zero, the other is in the noise floor). I will delete my comment above shortly.

Comment: After more careful checking, I get the same matrix now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the reduced form, you have the following equations:
$$x_5 = 1, \ \ x_1-2 x_3 + x_4 = 1, \ \ x_2+x_3 - x_4 = 2.$$
Since this gives $x_1 = 1+2x_3-x_4$ and $x_2 =2-x_3+x_4$, we can choose $x_3,x_4$ arbitrarily and determine the corresponding $x_1,x_2$. Hence the solution set is given by:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}+ x_3 \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + x_4 \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},$$
with $x_3, x_4$ arbitrary.

Comment: thank you guys, I solved it this morning, the solution was correct, I was insecure xD

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that OP has correctly brought the matrix to reduced row-echelon form.